# Is it possible, to create a wrapper around an existing program with GUI?(Windows)

Tags: windows, user-interface, automation, desktop-application, headless

At my company we have a really old program, maybe written in Delphi or something. We don't have the source code. The program works well, but we want to:

- Hide some features from the user.
- Prevent some actions, if the user doesn't have the right priviliges.
- Automate a sequence of actions inside the program, with a press of the button.

How could it be possible to write a wrapper program around this exisitng Windows application with GUI. Which:

- Hides the original underlaying programs GUI.
- Allows the user to control the underlaying program, but with our given rules.

The new program could be really simple, but I dont't know what are the right tools for this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) to pilot "automagically" the old program, since this language features native methods to programmatically interact with GUI, and probably can also hide / protect "dangerous" controls too.

You can even implement a new GUI (with AutoIt itself, BTW it uses an UI designer close to Delphi's one), just to wrap the one only controls you need, with preliminary consistency checks before sending them to the old GUI.

I successfully used AutoIt to automatically install programs that required user interaction during setup to properly install them (i.e. old MySql setups), so I don't see what would be impossible to do with it in your case.